# seemingly unnecessary python-sql class

Tags: python, sql, function

I met a function in python, it says:

```
class _Sqlite3Cursor(object):

    def __init__(self, cursor):
        self.cursor = cursor

    def fetchone(self):
        return self.cursor.fetchone()

    def fetchall(self):
        return self.cursor.fetchall()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        return self.cursor.next()
```

It seems that fetchone and fetchall return themselves and  do nothing else, is this class useful?

Comment: It may just exist as a placeholder.  If special handling is needed for other DB backends (e.g., MySQL), it can make sense to have one for Sqlite even if it doesn't do anything, so you have a place to make changes if you later do need to do something special for Sqlite.